# How do you correctly use /GUARD:CF MSVC flag?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cl

I am trying to use the `/GUARD:CD` MSVC flag. From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/guard-enable-guard-checks?view=msvc-160), it says

> The `/GUARD:CF` option must be specified to both the compiler and linker

The documentation also says that `/GUARD:CF` requires [the `/DYNAMICBASE` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/dynamicbase-use-address-space-layout-randomization?view=msvc-160) to also be set.

However, when I try to compile, I see warnings for unrecognized options:

```
cl -c /W3 /O2 /EHsc /MP /Zi /nologo /MD /Zi /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /LD -Isrc -Iimport/include -D_WINDOWS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL /GS /DYNAMICBASE /GUARD:CF    /Fo: redacted.cpp.obj redacted.cpp
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/GU'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/GD'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/G:'
cl : Command line warning D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/GC'
```

At first I thought maybe I accidentally introduced non-printable characters in my text editor, but I verified with `cat --show-nonprinting` that that was not the case.

How can I correctly pass `/GUARD:CF` to the MSVC `cl` compiler so that it recognizes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked is a part of the manual to MSVC linker options. Linker options are case-insensitive. That page has a link to the manual to MSVC compiler options:

> When source code is compiled by using the
> [/guard:cf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/guard-enable-control-flow-guard?view=msvc-160) option.

Compiler options are case-sensitive. The proper cl invocation

```
cl -c /W3 /O2 /EHsc /MP /Zi /nologo /MD /Zi /DUNICODE /D_UNICODE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /LD -Isrc -Iimport/include -D_WINDOWS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DWXUSINGDLL /GS /DYNAMICBASE /guard:cf  /Fo: redacted.cpp.obj redacted.cpp
```

Just to know. Disabling guard is different for the linker and the compiler: `/GUARD:NO` and `/guard:cf-`.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation you linked (which is about the *linker* `/GUARD` option) is rather misleading, but the answer is buried in there, if you look *really* hard:

For the *compiler*, the command-line option needs to be in lowercase (but the linker seems to accept either uppercase or lowercase).

So, use `/guard:cf` instead of `/GUARD:CF` on the `cl` command-line.

From the [linked document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/guard-enable-guard-checks?view=msvc-160):

> When source code is compiled by using the /guard:cf option, …

And, on the page that the [`/guard:cf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/guard-enable-control-flow-guard?view=msvc-160) links to, the switch is only ever given in lowercase.